# Number of Choices in a permutation given one option is fixed

Tags: statistics, permutation, probability

I am in doubt about result of the following :

Each person can choose whether to wear a **black tux or a grey tux**, and whether to wear **blue, yellow, or green** coloured tie. In how many ways will you distribute all possible sets to 6 different people and no set repeats *given that person 1 wants only a black tux.*

A possible explanation will be helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think this question belongs on this stackexchange website. However what the hell I'll answer anyway.

So there are 6 people that can choose from 2 sets, the tux (2 options) and the tie (3 options)

Let's simplify a bit, one person can choose from 6 (3 * 2) options. A person with a fixed tux choice will only have 3 (3 * 1) options.

So to calculate it, we first take the person with limited choice and multiply that with the options the others still have.

-> the total number of options would be 3 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 360

(At least I'm fairly certain, as with most on this exchange, I'm a programmer rather than a mathematician)

Answer (score 0):

For the suits you just subtract one person because one is already fixed.
The other 5 can each decide for one of 2 choices. This is similar to a coin flip for each person. That makes 2^5 combinations.
Then they choose the ties, where all 6 have 3 options. Following the example of the coin flip (but with 3 possible outcomes) we have 3^6 combinations for the ties. 
Now just add the options together, because the decisions between suit and tie don't depend on each other. This will give you 729 outcomes for the ties and 32 outcomes for the tux's.

Hope I could make things clearer for you.